# How to set up syncthing + disco server on Docker?

Tags: docker, syncthing

I'd like to run syncthing in Docker on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I also want to run my own discovery server.

How can I do this? Should they be in separate containers, or share a container? What is necessary to get it to work?